# OpenVPN On Dual Wan

Tags: centos, openvpn, iptables

I have a Dual-WAN Linux Box WAN1 & WAN2,

Installed on it OpenVPN Server, is there a way to make OpenVPN server accept connections from both interfaces, as it now it only accepts connection from the default WAN.

if it helps to do this i can have two openvpn configuration for each WAN.

Comment: what does the `local` directive look like in your openVPN config ont eh server, and what does `netstat -punta` show in regards to openVPN on the server?

Answer (score 0):

just solved it,

seems to be a routing issue, just marked the  packets destined to that port the with ip-rules added them to the desired table..